# Wordpress: changing only one page url from database

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In Wordpress I created a page "home" (https://sitedomain.com/home) but I cannot render it equal as the homepage (I made a page template equal to index.php and implemented the custom query but still not working properly).
I currently have a 
`echo("<script> window.location.replace('https://sitedomain.com')</script>");` 
statement in the single page template file allowing me to redirect users to the actual homepage but it is slow. I want to manually change the URL of this page in the database but I cannot find it in the Database.
Also, it is not possible to modify the URL from the dashboard since the minimum url must be https://sitedomain.com/home. 
Is it possible? Where to find the single URL of the page in the Database?

Answer (score 0):

You can just define that page as your homepage in the WP dashboard: "Settings > Read > select static page as starting page" (or similar, not sure about the exact English terms)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to keep the original homepage as a homepage, and I would like it to be dynamic :)

Comment: sorry, but it's not clear what you mean (?). You can set *any* page as your homepage in these settings

Comment: Yes but I do not want static page for my homepage. I want that it displays latest posts

Comment: You can create a page (i.e. a page template / php file) that dynamically displays your latest post and define that as "static homepage"

Answer (score 0):

in the end I simply used JQuery to replace the href attribute with the one that I needed (https://sitedomain.com). 
Not ideal solution but it works.